# Center img inside a div, vertical-align: middle

Tags: css

I was following a tutorial teaching how to center img inside a div. It is using line-high and vertical-align: middle. For example, this is the code in fiddle:

```
<div id="ad_unit">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="http://i760.photobucket.com/albums/xx243/jhonmarcanob2010/50x50.jpg" alt="image"/>
    </div>      
</div>


.logo {
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    width: 138px;
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}

.logo img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

But the image is not vertically centered when I try to put the code in a html file. Any thoughts?

Comment: I just realize I have this DOCTYPE in my html file: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">  If I get rid of PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd", it works, what's the logic behind this?

Comment: Using transitional will cause lots of quarks like this, read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode . It's best to remove it so it's rendered with HTML5 standards, so just use `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: I will remove it, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="ad_unit">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="http://i760.photobucket.com/albums/xx243/jhonmarcanob2010/50x50.jpg" alt="image" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.logo {
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;
}
.logo img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/justincook/yarzY/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am wondering how did you post the fiddle link here, when I tried to do that, I got an error said "link to fiddle must be accomplished by code"

Comment: By the way, I have a 4px offset in the line-height, so instead of line-height:300px, I need to do this line-height:296px to make it vertically centered. Do you have any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: For the link, I just copy/pasted the url. Make sure you add your code first, then add the jsfiddle link. If you try again it might work.

Comment: The offset sound like you have a 2px border, or 2px padding on one of the parent elements.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this little trick will help you. I'm using an inline-blocking div for this:

Try this HTML code:

```
<div id="ad_unit">
<div class="logo">
    <img src="http://i760.photobucket.com/albums/xx243/jhonmarcanob2010/50x50.jpg" alt="image"/>
    <div class="vcenter"></div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.logo {
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
    height: 300px;
}

.logo img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.logo .vcenter {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7FKma/)